# How to get a single model object using multiple ORM lookup parameters

Tags: django

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(age=23, sex='female')
```

This would return a queryset.

If I assume this queryset only contains one result, how to return that object directly?

Is there any way like using 'get'?

Comment: could you explain the title a bit more?

Comment: Did you try just using `get` instead of `filter` above?

Comment: I'll add an if to check exist(), anyway. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The title doesn't match the questions text

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Actually, you can pass multiple lookup parameters in QuerySet's [get() method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get). So how about?

```
try:
    employee = Employee.objects.get(age=23, sex='female')
except Employee.DoesNotExist:
    # no employee found
except Employee.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    # what to do if multiple employees have been returned?
```