# Django; is it possible to have a default value for queryset

Tags: django

```
employee = Employee.objects.filter('age' = 99)
```

We assume this queryset is empty.

If I use `employee[0]`, that will return index out of range error, so is it possible to have a None as default value here?

```
`employee[0] or None`? # This won't work, but this is what I mean.
```

Comment: BTW, try avoid try catch block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722375/how-to-represent-and-in-django-orm-query.....you should edit your old questions instead of asking new ones

Comment: @user469652 are you suggesting not to use try, except block? If so, why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just want to get a single instance, use [`get`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get), not `filter`:

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(age = 99)
```

If that doesn't exist, you'll get a `Employee.DoesNotExist` exception, which you'll need to catch. If there's more than one 99 year-old employee, you'll get a Employee.MultipleObjectsReturned exception, which you may want to catch.

There's always [django-annoying](http://skorokithakis.github.io/django-annoying/)'s `get_object_or_None` if you're feeling lazy!

```
from annoying.functions import get_object_or_None

obj = get_object_or_None(Employee, age=99)
```

If you don't want to use all of django-annoying, you can always add `get_object_or_None` somewhere, it just looks like this:

```
def get_object_or_None(klass, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Uses get() to return an object or None if the object does not exist.

    klass may be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet object. All other passed
    arguments and keyword arguments are used in the get() query.

    Note: Like with get(), a MultipleObjectsReturned will be raised if
    more than one object is found.
    """
    queryset = _get_queryset(klass)
    try:
        return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

Answer (score 8):

On Django >= 1.6 there's the `first` method, so you can just do:

```
employee = Employee.objects.filter(age=99).first()
```

Note, however, that this only makes sense if you know the QuerySet is guaranteed to return either 1 or 0 results.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
employee[0] if employee else None
```

Comment: I think this is same as employee[0] or None, will cause index out of range.

Comment: No, it is not. It is computing employee[0]'s value only if employee is True-like value. Empty QuerySet is false-like value, so if you have empty QuerySet, you'll get None.

Answer (score 1):

```
first_employee = employee[0] if employee.count() > 0 else None
```

Comment: This is bad. I'm not sure if it works at all, but even if it is you get two SQL-queries to database: one for count and one for employee itself. Django QuerySet is lazy so it is computed only when you're trying to fetch data for the first time. In this case you're trying to do this while writing employee.count(). Django passes "SECELE COUNT() FROM ..." query to your database and gives you a number back. But when you trying to do employee[0], Django has to query database once more! (Or fail at all, I'm not sure). Anyway, this is a very bad way to implement such an easy functionality.